# Possible causes of lost data received on a gigabit UDP connection?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I've written a custom C# program that receives about 1MByte/sec of UDP multicast data. Its running on a Gigabit NIC, connected to a dedicated server.

At some times of the day, when the network traffic is high, it loses UDP packets.

- If I have **two** copies of the program running, they all receive 100% of the UDP packets over an 8-hour period.
- If I have **three** copies of the program running, they all start **losing** the occasional **UDP packet** over the same 8-hour period.

In both cases, CPU usage is only about 15% peak.

How is this possible?

Comment: You know that UDP doesn't guarantee delivery right? ... packet loss is to be expected -- especially under load

Comment: @jtm001. Yes, I know this. However, in this case its irrelevant, as all copies of the program are monitoring the same UDP stream. In this case, the packet loss was occuring *after* the packet entered the NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually two buffers at work here: the hardware buffers (on the network card) and the windows side buffers (set in .NET). We reconfigured the hardware buffers on the network card to be 1024KB instead of 256KB, hopefully this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

UDP connections do not guarantee delivery of packets, if you need guaranteed delivery of packets use TCP instead.

There are various reasons for packet loss when using UDP, to list a few:

- Network congestion,
- Packet corruption,
- Faulty hardware.

Although you might only be using 15% of your CPU on your server (or client) this does not mean that you're not exhausting another resource (i.e. network throughput, router buffers). To me it sounds like you're suffering from network congestion potentially (as you've stated yourself that this only hpapens during times of high network traffic).

Comment: It looks like the solution was to increase the size of the hardware buffers on the network card.